# C++11 thread concepts with exception

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, exception

I understand that when using c++11 threads if join is not invoked on child thread , child thread might not be able to complete its processing for resources held by parent thread if the parent thread dies earlier, i also understand if an exception is thrown in parent thread before child gets to join with the parent, the same scenario will happen.
  I wrote below piece of code to get a hands on understanding of the concepts when an exception occurs.

```
typedef struct thread_method{
    void operator()(const std::string& message){
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000;i++);
        std::cout <<'\n'<<message;
    }
}thread_method;

void throwException() {
        std::cout <<'\n'<<"throwException";
        throw "Exception thrown";
}

void threadHandlingOne(void){
    std::string message = "Hello World";
    std::thread m_thread1 ( (thread_method()) ,
                            std::ref(message) );    

    try {
      throwException();      
    }catch (const char* err_message){
      std::cout <<'\n'<<err_message;
      m_thread1.join();
      throw err_message;
    }
}

int main(int argc , char** argv){
    threadHandlingOne();
    return 0;
}
```

However when running the program i keep getting 2 different outputs.

```
1 throwException
  Exception thrown

2 Hello World
  throwException
```

Both outputs doesn't make sense. For (1) why is parent thread not waiting for child to complete as join is called. For (2) child threads runs fine, but why is the catch not invoked?

Comment: One thing that might be an issue is that you do not print a terminating new line, so your terminal might be hiding the last line; please use `std::cout <<'\n'<<err_message<<'\n';`, just in case it is this simple issue.

Comment: @KenY-N , i would have never imagined this to be the culprit, i had been banging my head for an hour now , thanks again. this solved it.

Comment: I'd use a mutex to protect the stream outputs and also end every output with `std::endl` which flushes the stream.